# code coverage is high for zero test cases

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, code-coverage, coverage.py

I have a simple [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) app that doesn't have any test cases and I tried to get the test coverage using [**coverage**](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.1). The result was surprising,

```
coverage run --omit '*.virtual_env/*' ./manage.py test && coverage report                                                                                                                                
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
Name                           Stmts   Miss  Cover
--------------------------------------------------
django2x/__init__.py               0      0   100%
django2x/settings.py              20      0   100%
django2x/urls.py                   7      2    71%
manage.py                         12      2    83%
music/__init__.py                  0      0   100%
music/admin/__init__.py            1      0   100%
music/admin/actions.py             6      2    67%
music/admin/filters.py            12      5    58%
music/admin/model_admin.py        13      0   100%
music/admin/register.py            7      0   100%
music/filters.py                   7      0   100%
music/forms.py                     6      0   100%
music/migrations/__init__.py       0      0   100%
music/models.py                   28      4    86%
music/pagination.py                3      0   100%
music/serializers.py              54     18    67%
music/tests.py                     1      0   100%
music/urls.py                      9      0   100%
music/views.py                    30      1    97%
--------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                            216     34    84%
```

Why I have got **84%** test coverage from ***zero tests***?

Comment: If you just import a file, all of the import/def/class statements will be executed.  You don't have much real code in this project (judging from the statement counts), so just running the defining statements is getting you to 84%.